# How to make search result all in one box? Insted of (JOptionPane seperate boxes)

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Hello I have an `ArrayList` with 5 phones, 2 of them are  from "Samsung manufacture" 
how would I display them all in one? Instead of separate boxes?

```
String conta1 = "Samsung";
for(int i=0;i<PhoneList.size();i++){
    if(conta1.equalsIgnoreCase(PhoneList.get(i).getMfg())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,PhoneList.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `JLabels` and add them to a `JPanel`, using whatever layout you find fit. Then add *that* `JPanel` to the `JOptionPane`. Something like

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1);
for(int i=0; i<PhoneList.size(); i++){
if(conta1.equalsIgnoreCase(PhoneList.get(i).getMfg())){
    panel.add(new JLabel(PhoneList.get(i)); // not sure what .get(i) returns
}                                           // but it must be a string passed to the label
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
```

---

Note: As pointed out in comment, you need to pass a `String` to the `JLabel`. If there is a `toString()` in the object that `PhoneList.get(i)` returns, then call it (`PhoneList.get(i).toString()`). If each object's `toString()` method displays multiple lines, you can use HTML. You can google [How to add multiple lines to a JLabel](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20add%20multiple%20lines%20to%20a%20JLabel) for some answers to that.

---

**UPDATE**

See full example here using HTML. Note, you can always use more than one `JLabel` also in the loop. You could add thee labels the panel, each iteration. For integers, just use `String.valueOf(int)` to pass to the label.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class TwoLineLabel {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
        phones.add(new Phone("Galaxy", 12345));
        phones.add(new Phone("iPhone", 12345));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (Phone phone: phones) {
            String html = "<html><body style='width:100px'>Phone: " + phone.getName() 
                    + "<br/>Model: " + phone.getModel() + "</body></html>";
            JLabel label = new JLabel(html);
            label.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
            panel.add(label);

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Phone List", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

}

class Phone {
    private String name;
    private int model;

    public Phone(String name, int model) {
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: See the last part of my answer.

Comment: I need int and string some of them mixed, thanks though

Comment: I created a result arraylist , but now the problem it outprint all in one line... how to make them outpunt into 2 lines or more?

Comment: What is the class/object the `PhoneList.get(i)` returns? as a `toString()` method in that class representing the string representation. the call `PhoneList.get(i).toString()`

Comment: _"how to make them outpunt into 2 lines or more?"_ - See the link I posted. Search and you will find answers.

Comment: *"See my **UPDATE**"*  Nice answer, even **before** the update. :)  I'd probably just use a `JTable` for this, though. ;)